# Cannot load iframe in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I have been trying to load an section of page using `iframe` in my `wordpress` site. I can load certain sites in the `iframe` without any issue but while i try my required page it doesn't work as expected just inside the page. The `iframe` src is loading perfectly if its opened individually

I have tried most of the answers mentioned here in `stackoverflow` and other forums, still can't get a solution for this. I tried adding code in `.htaccess`, also tried adding code in `functions.php`

[This is the `iframe` src](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search;freeTextSearchKeyword=;typeCodes=1;statusCodes=31094501,31094502;programCode=H2020;programDivisionCode=31047879;focusAreaCode=null;crossCuttingPriorityCode=null;callCode=Default;sortQuery=openingDate;orderBy=asc;onlyTenders=false;topicListKey=topicSearchTablePageState) I want to load.

It can be loaded individually in browser but not inside an `iframe`. I am getting the following error in console while i try to load it :

[ERROR] Permission denied to access property "hash" on cross-origin object

Is this an issue with my code, server config or with the URL itself?

Thanks

Comment: Probably an issue with that site itself - trying to put it into a basic iframe in a jsfiddle also just results in errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about your source is blocking unauthorization call from domains not in CORS. They're only allow call from Origin https://ec.europa.eu. The short answer, you can't deal anything from your side.

[image: CORS]

More information about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS